# Представления символа в виде битов. Java

Tags: java

Допустим у меня есть символ `'C'`, и мне нужно получить его представление в двоичной системе, т.е. `1000011`

Как лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть способ такой:

```
char c = 'C'
Integer.toBinaryString((byte) c)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.toBinaryString('C');
```

Кстати, если погуглить, то вы найдёте очень много абсолютно таких же ответов: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606740/converting-a-character-to-its-binary-value)